# Google Sheets e.values replaceText based on input

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I want to find a way to automate this process of writing cover letters. I'm applying for several different job positions and i keep making mistakes when I write my cover letters (wrong position/wrong company, etc.)

I want to automate this based on a couple factors. I followed [this tutorial](https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2018/09/17/auto-fill-google-doc-from-google-form-submission/) to generate cover letters based on responses to a Google form. it worked really well, but i wanted to add something to it. here's my code:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var todaysDate = e.values[1];
  var dearWho = e.values[2];
  var position = e.values[3];
  var companyName = e.values[4];
  var thingName = e.values [5];
  var feelingsTime = e.values [6]; 
  var otherComments = e.values [7];
  var letterBody = e.values [8];

  //file is the template file, and you get it by ID
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1a-qF9vzbXWyRPdKYTIn0RmH4yK8PP4ZvkQ6kITSTXZg"); 
  
  //We can make a copy of the template, name it, and optionally tell it what folder to live in
  //file.makeCopy will return a Google Drive file object
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("158SpuE8urUej7JCaJfym8roi_uAdyu--")
  var copy = file.makeCopy(todaysDate + '_' + companyName + '_' + position ); 
  
  //Once we've got the new file created, we need to open it as a document by using its ID
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  
  //Since everything we need to change is in the body, we need to get that
  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  
  //Then we call all of our replaceText methods
  body.replaceText('{{todaysDate}}', todaysDate); 
  body.replaceText('{{dearWho}}', dearWho);  
  body.replaceText('{{position}}', position); 
  body.replaceText('{{companyName}}', companyName); 
  body.replaceText('{{thingName}}', thingName);  
  body.replaceText('{{feelingsTime}}', feelingsTime); 
  body.replaceText('{{otherComments}}', otherComments);
  e.values [8] = ("Editor") ? body.replaceText('{{letterBody}}', "editor cover letter body")
  
 //Lastly we save and close the document to persist our changes
  doc.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

What I want to do now is answer "editor" for the last question on the form, and have it pick out the right letter body for that position. I've written a couple different paragraphs tailored to each of the positions.

I tried *something*  with this line:

```
e.values [8] = ("Editor") ? body.replaceText('{{letterBody}}', "editor cover letter body")
```

but I'm not really sure what the proper function should be.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot understand what you are trying to do, maybe you can try to describe in different words and more in detail - maybe providing images and samples? Do you want to edit the answer of a Google from response? Is "editor" the question or answer of the Google form? What do you mean by " have it pick out the right letter body for that position"?

Comment: @ziganotschka Hi, my post was edited so some context was lost. "Editor" is one of the positions I'm applying for. So when I complete the google form, those answers go into a spreadsheet, which is what `var todaysDate = e.values[1];` is pulling from to replace the text in the generated document. What I want to do is have one of the questions be something simple, like "what position is this", but the text that replaces it in the generated doc to be one of the pre-written bodies to the letter tailored to each position, now what the answer is on the spreadsheet.

Comment: So when you answer the question "what position is this" with "Editor", you want the placeholder {{letterBody}} to be replaced with a text from a spreadsheet correponding to they keyword "editor"? Does it mean you have a table in a spreadsheet with key words and corresponding replacement texts? Can you show a copy of this spreadsheet to understand the structure?